# npm install "no such file or directory '.../package.json'" for custom modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I have some folders symlinked to `node_modules` in order to be able to `import` them as modules. For example, I have `src/client/apps/admin` directory which is symlinked to `node_modules/@admin`. But npm gives me these warnings when I'm trying to install or remove any modules

```
$ npm i -S connect-roles
...

npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Admin/Code/www/learn/src/client/apps/admin/assets/package.json'
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Admin/Code/www/learn/src/client/apps/admin/components/package.json'
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Admin/Code/www/learn/src/client/apps/admin/reducers/package.json'
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Admin/Code/www/learn/src/client/apps/admin/package.json'
```

Of course, I can just add `package.json` to every such folder but I don't want to. There has to be another better way to do that. Is there?

PS: npm v3.5.3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

None of the answers helped me to solve the problem so I created my own package  [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias), which is highly inspired by [`app-module-path`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-module-path). This package allows registering aliases of directories for further usage with `require`/`import`.

Example:

```
const moduleAlias = require('module-alias')

moduleAlias.addAliases({
  '@root'  : __dirname,
  '@server': __dirname + '/src/server'
})

const someModule = require('@server/some-module')
```

Read the readme for more examples

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use nodes module `require`/`import` in a way that is bound to cause you problems later on. It would be much better to structure your project in a way that does away with these symlinks.

When importing a module you can specify a core module, a module installed inside your projects *node_modules*, or a relative path:

**Core modules** (eg `require('http')`)
Core modules are included as part of node and can be imported simply by name.

**Installed modules** (eg `require ('bluebird')`)
Modules that have been installed via `npm`, and are inside your projects _node_modules_ directory, can be installed using the name declared in their `package.json`.

**Relative paths** (eg `require('../settings/menu')`)
Modules (that could be single files with no package definition) can be imported using a path relative from the importing file.

Because you are not providing a `package.json`, npm is failing because it's unable to lookup the `name` property of each package. You will be much better off if you simply require these files using a relative path.

For instance, if your project looks something like:

```
apps  
│
└───admin
    │   assets.js
    │   components.js
    |   reducers.js
    │
    ├───subfolder
    │   │   thing.js
```

You can import one file to another with a relative path.

Eg, in `components.js`:

`require ('./assets')`

Or in `thing.js`:

`require ('../assets')`

If you have a lot of very nested paths, this can become a little cumbersome, but there are a number of suggested ways this can be dealt with. One method is to use `path.resolve()` which will resolve the relative path, given a path from the project route.

For example:

`require ('../assets')`

could be re-written as

`require (path.resolve('app/admin/assets'))`

This has the nice result of all your require paths being 'absolute' from your project root.

You can read more suggested ways to deal with this in [Better local require() paths for Node js](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I, of course, know that I can use relative paths. But my project is getting quite big with lots of subfolders, so I tired of messing with requiring modules in a way like `import some from '../../../../../../some_module'` or `import some from '../../../../../client/apps/admin/components/pages/some-page'`

Comment: See additional info above.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I will try one of the suggestions, this one is probably what I was looking for https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-load. Hope it solve my problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

Try this command:

```
npm install -g npm-autoinit
```